# Obtener subcategoría en la categoría obtenida

Tags: php, pdo

Lo que estoy tratando de construir es el siguiente. Obtener todas las categorías de mi menú y mostrarlos, a continuación, buscar todas las subcategorías para cada categoría especial todos lo muestran también. Espero que entiendas lo que quiero y digo. Me perdí en el código y no ahora cómo hacerlo. Aquí está mi código, para menú de niveles(múltiples dinámicamente) espero que pueda ayudarme.

Aquí está la estructura de la tabla

```
|-------------------------------------|
|subcategory table                    |
|-------------------------------------|
| id | subcategory_name | id_category |
|-------------------------------------|


|---------------|
|category table |
|---------------|
| id | category |
|---------------|
```

`Id_category` está conectado con `id` en la tabla de `categorías`.

**index.php:**

```
public function Category()
    {
        $db = getBD();
        $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM category");
        $sql->execute();
        $data = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        foreach ($data as $row) {

                $row['category']; 


                $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM subcategory WHERE id = '".$row['id']."'");
                $sql->execute();
                $sdata = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                    foreach ($sdata as $row) {
                        $row['subcategory_name'];
                    }
        }
    }
```

**category.php:**

```
$object = new myObject();

$menu = $object->Category();

    foreach ($menu as $row) {

        echo "<a href='#'>".$row['category']."</a>"; //Menu
            echo "<a href='#'>".$row['subcategory_name']."</a>"; //Sub Menu

    }
```

Comment: Creo que la consulta de subcategoría debiera ser `"SELECT * FROM subcategory WHERE id_category = '".$row['id']."'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depende:

1. Cada categoria tiene una sola subcategoria
2. Cada categoria tiene varias subcategorias

Asumo que es la opcion 2 ya que haces un foreach en la segunda consulta

**index.php**:

```
public function Category()
{
    $db = getBD();
    $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM category");
    $sql->execute();
    $data = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    //array para devolver el menu
    $menu = array();

    foreach ($data as $categ) {
        //$categ seria un registro de la tabla categoria - primer foreach
        //NO VA AQUI
        //$menu[] = $categ;


        $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM subcategory WHERE id = '".$categ['id']."'");
        $sql->execute();
        $sdata = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        //no uses la misma variable para el segundo foreach o 
        //sobreescribiras la variable anterior

        $categ['subcategorias'] = array();

        foreach ($sdata as $subcateg) {
            //asignas las subcategorias como un array
            $categ['subcategorias'][] = $subcateg;
            }
        //VA AQUI
        $menu[] = $categ;
        }
    return $menu;
}
```

Si usaste la opcion 2 entonces cambiaria el codigo en **category.php**:

```
$object = new myObject();

$menu = $object->Category();

foreach ($menu as $categ) {

    echo "<a href='#'>".$categ['category']."</a>"; //Menu

    //haces otro foreach para obtener cada subcategoria
    foreach($categ['subcategorias'] as $subcat) {
        echo "<a href='#'>".$subcat['subcategory_name']."</a>"; //Multiple Sub Menu
    }

}
```

**Opinion Personal**: en el **foreach** te recomiendo usar nombres de variables que indiquen lo que obtienes de cada bucle ($categoria, $subcategoria, $usuario, etc) en vez de usar simplemente **$row**, asi el codigo sera mas facil de entender tanto para ti como para cualquiera que lo lea.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda. pero dice Notice: Undefined index: subcategorias y es valor o tabla ?

Comment: cual es el error completo (linea y archivo)?

Comment: en la segunda consulta deberia ser $categ['id']

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: subcategorias in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\category.php on line 10

Comment: Ya corregi el error en index.php: la asignacion `$menu[] = $categ;` va despues del segundo foreach, para que queden agregadas las subcategorias.. sorry :)

Comment: si funciona, Gracias :)

Comment: Recuerda calificar la respuesta si fue de utilidad!

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55367/discussion-between-diego-sagredo-and-carlos-gonzalez).